# Разбить номер кузова автомобиля на frame и frame_no

Tags: php

Собственно сабж

Есть задача из строки вида `SG5014763` (номер кузова Subaru) или `XZU4230001026` (номер кузова Toyota) получить `SG5-014763` и `XZU423-0001026` соответственно.

Регулярное выражение тут вряд ли поможет. Может кто-нибудь знает какую-нибудь библиотеку для этого?

**UPD**: Номер кузова, к примеру, Toyota может быть вида как `XZU423-0001026` так и `ST215-0003437`.

**UPD**: Дело в том, что это не VIN-номер, а именно номер кузова. С VIN номером всё понятно, его разбивать не надо. API которое возвращает мне данные об автомобиле по VIN-номеру его разделения не требует, а вот что бы идентифицировать авто по номеру кузова (на сколько я понимаю это ток японские авто) API требует два параметра, а обычный пользователь не всегда знает как разбить его номер кузова правильно.

**UPD**: В общем решил собирать статистику по вводимым номерам, и для каждой марки в ручную пытаться понять "маску"

Comment: Ну если абстрагироваться от того что это вин-номер, по каким правилам вы хотите разбивать/форматировать строку?

Comment: В строке номера субару дефис нужно ставить на третью позицию, а тоёты на шестую. Если знаем марку машины, то особых проблем здесь нет и сомневаюсь, что может быть библиотека для подобных вещей.

Comment: а марку машины можно идентифицировать по длинне номера. правильно?

Comment: @koks_rs, у японцев первая часть (до дефиса) это грубо говоря код всей линейки модели (грубо говоря все Toyota Allion 4WD с 2007 по 2015 год имеют первую часть ZTR265), а после дефиса это уже конкретный номер конкретного транспортного средства с завода

Comment: @Arik, неа (Toyota может быть вида как XZU423-0001026 так и ST215-0003437)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, думаю нет, с каждым годом мне кажется длина номера становится длиннее (ну или с каждым десятилетием) :) да и одинаковая длина у некоторых марок

Comment: @Vladimir Тогда выходит, что неважно сколько букв вначале, дефис ставится после трёх цифр?

Comment: @Vladimir, а у вас нет под рукой файлика с разными характерными номерами, с **уже** расставленными дефисами? на его основе можно было бы попробовать составить регулярное выражение. чем больше разных по структуре номеров будет в этом файле, тем надёжнее оно (выражение) будет.

Comment: @Vladimir, значит на входе есть строка переменной длины и ее нужно разбить на две строки.  При этом не известно ни одного правила разделения ? Если так, то попробуйте просто в цикле делить строку на две части, перебирая все варианты. Сначала дефис после первой буквы, потом второй и ждать пока прийдет что-то от API кроме ошибки.

Comment: @Arik, в тойоте возможно так. Сам обратил на это внимание, хорошая идея. Получается нужно закономерность выискать во всех марках, и для каждой создать маску. Где б теперь взять большую базу реальных номеров кузовов. :) Вот как раз я и думал может уже где-то написанная библиотека готовая есть :)

Comment: @alexanderbaraki, к сожалению нет. Буду собирать базу значит

Comment: @koks_rs, думаю это не самый лучший вариант ;)

Comment: @Vladimir, однозначно далеко не лучший. Но 100% рабочиий :)

Comment: @Vladimir Попробовал найти в интернете «тоёта боди намберс» - выдаёт только ВИН. Даже если выйдет найти библиотеку для одной-двух автомобильных компаний, всё равно для всех такого не будет и придётся самостоятельно решать данную проблему.

Comment: @Vladimir, пока бросилась в глаза одна закономерность: дефис стоит между не-нулём и нулём. может быть, в первой части вообще не может быть нулей, а вторая с нуля начинается?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, у моей машины вторая часть начинается с тройки :)

Comment: @koks_rs, это точно :)))))

Comment: @Vladimir, ну, пока вы привели только три примера разбиения. можно хоть сейчас писать регулярное выражение, но с огромной долей вероятности уже четвёртый (пока не озвученный) номер будет разбит неверно. чем больше примеров разбиения сможете привести, тем достовернее будет регулярное выражение для разбивки.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, так вот и решил собирать реальные данные вводимые пользователем. Ещё написал письмо компании предоставляющей API. Как мне кажется на уровне БД это реализовать намного намного проще, чем мне. Добавляем третье поле, где сконкотенированы поля frame и frame_no в одно, и готово :)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25478/discussion-on-question-by-vladimir------frame--fr).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

зафиксирую пока то, что есть:

```
SG5-014763
ST215-0003437
XZU423-0001026
RN1-1000002
G50-301470
GYL15-2417961
SGL5-400683
CK2A-0403374
SG5-014763
XZU423-0001026

M100S-0013352
EK3-3408642
NKR66E-7527125
BJ8W-101901
N74W-0003227
N30-204020
SF5-069787
TD32W-100109
KZN185-9034662
```

и регулярное выражение, которое эти три номера (после удаления «минусов» в первой строке) возвращает к исходному состоянию:

```
cat file.s.nomerami | sed s/-// | \ 
  sed -r '
    s/^([A-Z][0-9]{2})([0-9]{6,7})$/\1-\2/;
    s/^([A-Z][0-9]{2,3}[A-Z])([0-9]{7})$/\1-\2/;
    s/^([A-Z]{2}[0-9])([0-9]{6,7})$/\1-\2/;
    s/^([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{1,2}[A-Z])([0-9]{6,7})$/\1-\2/;
    s/^([A-Z]{2,3}[0-9]{3})([0-9]{7})$/\1-\2/;
    s/^([A-Z]{3}[0-9]{1,2})([0-9]{6,7})$/\1-\2/;
    s/^([A-Z]{3}[0-9]{2}[A-Z])([0-9]{7})$/\1-\2/;
  '
```

в выражении сейчас огрмное количество избыточности: стрельба из пушки по воробьям. но пусть будет «про запас».

ждём больше примеров разбиения…

Comment: в любом случае нужно писать регулярку под каждую марку отдельно, так и выражение будет проще и точнее. На данный момент это:

`Honda - RN1-1000002`
`Infiniti - G50-301470`
`Lexus - GYL15-2417961`
`Mazda - SGL5-400683`
`Mitsubishi - CK2A-0403374`
`Subaru - SG5-014763`
`Toyota - XZU423-0001026`

Comment: вам, конечно виднее по поводу номеров и марок. мне регулярные выражения более близки и понятны. и дополнил регулярное выражение, заменив `{6}` на `{6,7}` (можно было учесть четвёртый номер ещё как минимум тремя способами, но этот наиболее простой)

Comment: кстати уже можно заметить, что вторая часть состоит только из цифр

Comment: Нашёл вот такую подсказку http://jsfiddle.net/cajLg63L/, не известно как это соответствует конечно более свежим машинам

Comment: добавил новых правил и упростил конструкцию. те номера, что вы нашли на jsfiddle — они достоверны? можно добавлять в список?

Comment: в jsfiddle это я добавил, коллега поделился, когда то давным давно он это использовал, достоверность не 100 процентная

Comment: ну, пусть будет.

Comment: В общем спасибо большое. Сейчас начал собирать вводимые номера, какое-то время буду пропускать их через регулярки, если всё нормально, то пойдёт в продакшн :)

Comment: упростил, переупорядочил, чтоб проще было ориентироваться.

Answer (score 0):

В общем благодаря @alexanderbarakin в итоге получилась функция для PHP:

```
public function parseFrameNo($str) {
    $replacement_count = 0;

    $str = preg_replace('/[^A-Z0-9]/', '', strtoupper($str));

    $str = preg_replace('/^([A-Z][0-9]{2})([0-9]{6,7})$/', '$1-$2', $str, -1, $replacement_count);
    if (!$replacement_count) $str = preg_replace('/^([A-Z][0-9]{2,3}[A-Z])([0-9]{7})$/', '$1-$2', $str, -1, $replacement_count);
    if (!$replacement_count) $str = preg_replace('/^([A-Z]{2}[0-9])([0-9]{6,7})$/', '$1-$2', $str, -1, $replacement_count);
    if (!$replacement_count) $str = preg_replace('/^([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{1,2}[A-Z])([0-9]{6,7})$/', '$1-$2', $str, -1, $replacement_count);
    if (!$replacement_count) $str = preg_replace('/^([A-Z]{2,3}[0-9]{3})([0-9]{7})$/', '$1-$2', $str, -1, $replacement_count);
    if (!$replacement_count) $str = preg_replace('/^([A-Z]{3}[0-9]{1,2})([0-9]{6,7})$/', '$1-$2', $str, -1, $replacement_count);
    if (!$replacement_count) $str = preg_replace('/^([A-Z]{3}[0-9]{2}[A-Z])([0-9]{7})$/', '$1-$2', $str, -1, $replacement_count);

    return $str;
}
```

На сколько она верна покажет время.

Что бы в итоге функция возвращала части, а не строку заменяем `preg_replace` на `preg_match` с небольшими доработками, а можно не париться и использовать `explode()`